# auditctl -l shows only few rules

Tags: centos, linux-audit

i am using

> `/etc/audit/rules.d/*.rules`

files to generate the

> /etc/audit/audit.rules

which has 120 lines.

But if i run

> `auditctl -l`

i get only 14 lines as a result though.

Why is this happening ?

Comment: Please provide more detailed information, ex: input and output files

Comment: The usual problem is a typo or other error in the rules.   The audit configuration ***stops*** on the first error (which nowadays is reported in the system logs).  Without showing those rules (and identifying the platform), this question has no valid answers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute `augenrules`.

This is an executable script that goes over the rules you have in rules.d and compiles them into a single valid file.

For that reason, you should also make sure that all the files in rules.d end with a new line. Otherwise, the resulting file will have a invalid rules.

You may not have that script if you are using an older version of auditd. But in fact, it is just a script, and you can take it from a newer version of auditd and place it somewhere in the path. Although, I would not recommend it, instead, if that is the case, you should upgrade auditd to a newer version.

Comment: I have the same problem, but I already ran augenrules (the systemd unit does it automatically too) and still only one of my added rules shows in the -l command.

Comment: Did you solve this issue?